# Can I load all routes from /routes/ with fs.readdir and mount with app.use(...)?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to learn how to use Express and I noticed some repetition in my app.js in the form of:

```
var index = require('./routes/index')
  , login = require('./routes/login')
  , register = require('./routes/register')
  , logout = require('./routes/logout')
  , posts = require('./routes/posts')
  , user = require('./routes/user');
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/login', login);
app.use('/register', register);
app.use('/logout', logout);
app.use('/posts', posts);
app.use('/user', user);
```

I wondered if it was possible to use fs.readdir to get all routes from /routes and then iterate over them running app.use(...). I first tried:

```
routeFiles = fs.readdir('./routes/', function(err, files) {
  _.each(files, function(file) {
    name = file.split('.')[0]
    app.use("'/" + name + "', " + name);
  });
});
```

and got the following error:

```
TypeError: app.use() requires middleware functions
at Function.use (/Users/.../application.js:17
```

I'm guessing this is because a string ("name") is being passed to app.use as opposed to the route function itself (as declared originally above with all the other variable declarations). Next, I tried declaring the function variables for each route inside the _.each function so that I could pass them directly and not just a string of the route name:

```
routeFiles = fs.readdir('./routes/', function(err, files) {
  _.each(files, function(file) {
    name = file.split('.')[0];
    app.use('\'/' + name + '\', ' + require('./routes/' + name));
  });
});
```

I still, however, get the following error:

```
/Users/.../lib/application.js:178
throw new TypeError('app.use() requires middleware functions');
      ^
TypeError: app.use() requires middleware functions
at Function.use (/Users/.../lib/application.js:178:11)
```

I'm going round in circles with this so I was hoping someone here could help me out. Please let me know if this is a stupid idea and something I shouldn't consider; as I said, I'm new to Express (and JS, really) so I'm just playing and wondering. Thanks!

**Update**: Here's an example route so you can see what I'm trying to load. In this case, it's a simple route for the index page.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// [GET] index
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Home',
    user: req.user
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last approach with the `require` could work - your route files would have to look like this though:

```
module.exports = function(req, resp, next){
     // your middleware code here
};
```

This is because the parameters of `app.use` in the path case are a path and a function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Benjamin. I've updated my post with a sample route; I should have had this in there from the start actually. I know it's not the same structure as what you mentioned but I thought exporting _router_ like this would achieve the same thing. I guess not.

Comment: No that won't work - you need to change your routes to the format I've specified in the answer for it to work or alternatively have then functions that take an app as a parameter and call them with your app.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification; I appreciate it. Do you have any opinion on mounting routes like this? I guess a lot of people would just leave it as is but it's nice to DRY things up when possible.

Comment: I usually have short routes so I don't put them in that many separate files but your application logic is different from mine so it really depends.